# one to one onto and composition functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm kind of confused about how to prove one to one and onto with functions and composition functions. I am also a visual learner. Could someone tell me step by step how to prove whether or not a function is one to one and if it is onto? Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using the search bar at the top of the website?

Comment: And see [Composition of injections (proof)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871871/composition-of-injections-proof) for injections.